# Converting EmailMessage to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, arrays

I am fetching email from Exchange server using Java EWS API (EWS - Exchange Web Services) and storing it in a proprietary CMS. The type in which I am getting message is `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage` - a class provided by EWS API. The CMS API requires `ByteArrayOutputStream` object as a parameter to its method.

So I want to convert `EmailMessage` object to `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837698/converting-any-object-to-a-byte-array-in-java) and tried similar like this: (Below `item` is of type `EmailMessage`)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try
{
    ObjectOutputStream o  = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject((Object)item);
}
catch(IOException ioe)   
{
    ioe.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

But I am getting

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)   
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
```

I am able to save these `EmailMessage` objects in `.eml` format using `FileOutputStream`, however now I am not able to find the way to convert them to `ByteArrayOutputStream`.
So is there any way to convert `FileOutputStream` to `ByteArrayOutputStream` or just directly from `EmailMessage` to `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: If you can write it out on the source machine, maybe you can use `FileInputStream` to read it in and convert that to `ByteArrayOutputStream` like the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19689394/151234

Comment: Yes actually I tried it like - fetching mail from exchange - saving it locally - moving to repository from local path, but now I want to handle this all in-memory, I mean I dont want to store mails on local drive. Thats why I want to convert it directly from `EmailMessage`, or to be precise without calling `write()` on `FileOutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because your `(Object)item`'s class not implementing `Serializable` interface. From java doc [writeObject(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Exceptions are thrown for problems with the OutputStream and for classes that should not be serialized. All exceptions are fatal to the OutputStream, which is left in an indeterminate state, and it is up to the caller to ignore or recover the stream state.

Comment: Yess I know that but is there anyway around?